# Not able to identity text box and enter text

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Using firepath  found the xpath of the text box, but selenium cannot identity and add text.

```
<div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide little more `html`?

Comment: Please share html code related to that textbox..

Comment: <div class="dynFilter" onclick="jQuery.jmesa.createDynFilter(this, 'promotionDefinitionsTable','eventInfo.name')"></div>

Comment: That's all I get for that item in the html

Comment: Is it a Jquery popup you are waiting for? Have you added any explicit wait for it to appear? See this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221453/how-to-handle-multiple-jquery-popup-with-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify a div's text with Selenium. The sendKeys() method can write only in the input fields. Use Javascript instead:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('some_id').innerHTML = "Test");
```

If you want to find an element by XPath using Javascript, use **document.evaluate**.

Example: https://coderwall.com/p/u2amea/javascript-get-element-by-xpath

Comment: What does "some_id" refer in your solution?

Comment: For example if you have an element like <div id="test"></div> then you have to use **document.getElementById("test")**